# Applying font size to a div and selector priority for * tag

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-size

This may be a bit stupid, but I'm having a problem with the font size of text inside a div.

In my CSS I have used

```
*{
   font-size: 16px;      
 }
 #newsletter{
   font-size: 14px;
 }
```

When I do this Chromes Element Inspector shows that it is using the 16px from the * selector.

When I use

```
#newsletter p{
font-size: 14px;
}
```

That works, I know that It uses that because it is a more specific selector, but why doesn't it pick up the 14px set to the #newsletter selector, it is further down in the CSS so it should take priority, does it not work because the * selector takes priority for some reason, or does setting font-size on a div not work, does it have to be on the #newsletter p selector instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 #newsletter *{
   font-size: 14px;
 }
```

You probably want to apply the font-size to all children of newsletter

Answer (score 2):

When you have any element (`p` in this case) inside another element (the element with `id=newsletter` in this case), then the styling of the inner element is always based on its own CSS properties. In this case, the only rule that assigns `font-size` to the inner element is `*{ font-size: 16px; }` so it takes effect. Anything that you set on outer elements cannot possibly affect this.

This is part of the CSS [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

If you want to set a fixed font size for the element with `id=newsletter` and all of its descendants (inner elements), you can set

```
#newsletter, #newsletter * { font-size: 14px }
```

A more structured approach is

```
body { font-size: 16px }
#newsletter { font-size: 14px }
```

When you don’t otherwise set font size, then elements will inherit from `body` or from the element with `id=newsletter`, depending on their placement.

An even better approach, with the same basic logic but with font size automatically adjusting to browser settings (user preferences) is

```
body { font-size: 100%; } /* logically not needed, helps against some bugs though */
#newsletter { font-size: 0.875em; } /* 14/16, giving 14px for body font size 16px */
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use body instead of *. That will achieve the same thing without having specificity issues.

```
body {
   font-size: 16px;      
}

#newsletter {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```